# Re-usable, Self Host SVG icons in CSS pseudo elements (`:before` and `:after`)

Tags: html, css, svg, pseudo-element, self-hosting

### Background

I have recently read an article which talks about [self-hosting your static assets](https://csswizardry.com/2019/05/self-host-your-static-assets/) and explains the risk of using CDN's or external infrastructure. This got me to think on hosting fonts & icons myself.

I'm aware that you can [self-host fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890950/self-hosting-downloaded-font) by downloading a font and using the file-path as a URL - to include that in your CSS. And you can also download or create an SVG for any icon and use it as a HTML element.

### Question

But **is it possible** to use a self-hosted SVG in a CSS pseudo element like in the content property `:before` and `:after`? Similar to how [Font Awesome allows you to mention content code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20782415/6908282) for their icons

Note: My main intention is re-usability of same SVG in multiple CSS classes

Comment: Or use a Web Component that does it for you:``<svg-icon is="menu">`` https://iconmeister.github.io

Answer (score 1):

Yes, through the data URIs; using the brackground or content property.

```css
.icon::before {
  display: inline-block;
  content:'';
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}

.icon-menu::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 30 30'%3e%3cpath stroke='rgba%280, 0, 0, 0.55%29' stroke-linecap='round' stroke-miterlimit='10' stroke-width='2' d='M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Developer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="icon icon-menu"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Andres. My main intention is re-usability. This way I would have to copy paste the URI in every class. And preferably, I'm looking for a way to use SVG in the CSS content property as a content code.